# Logical Equivalence as an equivalence relation

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I've been given the following problem for homework and I'm struggling with where to begin

"Suppose we have a set of 5 propositional variables, denoted L. By considering logical equivalence, what is the number of equivalence classes of propositional terms that are given the value true by 13 valuations on the set of propositional terms made up of elements of L?"

I know that logical equivalence is an equivalence relation and hence the equivalence classes of propositional terms partitions the set of all possible propositional terms, but other than that I'm not really sure how to start. Could anyone give me any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Two propositional terms are equivalent iff they have the same truth value for all valuations. Since it's possible to write a propositional term that's true for a given set of valuations, it follows that there is exactly one equivalence class for each subset of the set of valuations. There are $2^5=32$ valuations of the $5$ variables, and $\binom{32}{13}=347373600$ $13$-element subsets of this set of valuations, so that's the desired number of equivalence classes.